# MongoDB Replica Set - getting error "nodename nor servname provided, or not known" while connecting

Tags: python, mongodb, server

MongoDB V3.6.15

I am try to setting up replica set with 1 primary, 1 secondary and 1 arbiter. getting the error while connecting to Replica Set.
"pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: rep2:27017: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known,rep1:27017: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known,rep0:27017: 
[Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known"

Please find below the result for rs.config();

{
    "_id" : "XXXXXXXXX",
    "version" : 3,
    "protocolVersion" : NumberLong(1),
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "host" : "rep0:27017",
            "arbiterOnly" : false,
            "buildIndexes" : true,
            "hidden" : false,
            "priority" : 1,
            "tags" : {

```
        },
        "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
        "votes" : 1
    },
    {
        "_id" : 1,
        "host" : "rep1:27017",
        "arbiterOnly" : false,
        "buildIndexes" : true,
        "hidden" : false,
        "priority" : 1,
        "tags" : {

        },
        "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
        "votes" : 1
    },
    {
        "_id" : 2,
        "host" : "rep2:27017",
        "arbiterOnly" : true,
        "buildIndexes" : true,
        "hidden" : false,
        "priority" : 0,
        "tags" : {

        },
        "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
        "votes" : 1
    }
],
"settings" : {
    "chainingAllowed" : true,
    "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : 2000,
    "heartbeatTimeoutSecs" : 10,
    "electionTimeoutMillis" : 10000,
    "catchUpTimeoutMillis" : -1,
    "catchUpTakeoverDelayMillis" : 30000,
    "getLastErrorModes" : {

    },
    "getLastErrorDefaults" : {
        "w" : 1,
        "wtimeout" : 0
    },
    "replicaSetId" : ObjectId("5dd267845cdd7ff56f6c0fe5")
}
```

}

What is wrong that i done in configuring the replica set.

thanks in advance.

code using to connect to database.

```
import os
import pymongo
import ssl
import urllib
MONGODB_URL="mongodb://user:"+urllib.quote("password")+"@rep0xxxxxxxxxx:27017,rep1xxxxxxxxxx:27017,rep2xxxxxxxxxx:27017/admin?ssl=false&replicaSet=replicaname"
client = pymongo.MongoClient(
    MONGODB_URL
)
db = client.get_default_database()
print (db.collection_names())
```

```
Steps

1. Create 3 VMs on Azure Cloud in a same resource group

2. Install MongoDB 3.6.15 on all the Machines

3. Add User on the 3 machines.
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "xxxxxxxxx",
    pwd: "xxxxxxxxx",
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" }, "readWriteAnyDatabase" ]
  }
);
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "xxxxxxxxx",
    pwd: "xxxxxxxxx",
    roles: [ { role: "clusterAdmin", db: "admin" }, "readWriteAnyDatabase" ]
  }
);

4. Generate a Key using OpenSSL
openssl rand -base64 756 > /home/rep0/repkey
chmod 400 /home/rep2/repkey
sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /home/rep0/repkey

5. Edit /etc/mongod.conf to enable authentication
security:
  authorization: enabled
  keyFile: /home/rep0/repkey

6. Restart the 3 machines

7. Edit /etc/mongod.conf to add replica set config
replication:
  replSetName: myReplica
  enableMajorityReadConcern: false

8. Restart the 3 machines

9. Add the hosts on all the VM's
Private-IP-Address rep0
Private-IP-Address rep1
Private-IP-Address rep2

10. Open MongoShell for primary machine (one of the 3)

11. execute the command to start replica set and add secondaries.
rs.initiate();
rs.add();
rs.add("host":"rep1");
rs.addArb("rep2");

12. import sample data on the primary machine and confirm the same is replicated on the secondary machines
```

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to connect?

Comment: @JoeDrumgoole Yes, sure...I have updated the code in the post.

Comment: Can you ping those nodes you list as replica set members? Can you connect with the mongo shell?

Comment: @JoeDrumgoole I am unable to ping the secondary machines from the primary one...but, I am able to connect to mongo shell from primary to secondary. what is that i am missing on?

Comment: Post your ping command and your mongo shell command output

Comment: ping secondary-machine-host;  ping doesn't work and I get "4 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss" as result. I have added steps that i follow to set up replica set. please let me know if i am missing on any. thanks

Comment: If you can't ping them you don't have network connectivity. That is required for the replicas to communicate. Establishing network connectivity between your nodes is not something I can troubleshoot for you.

Comment: I understand. I will do that. Just a request, if you can validate the steps i am following. i have added the same in the post.